# print worksheets to pdf

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a macro to go through all of the worksheets in my workbook.

What i want to accomplish is to exportt each worksheet as a pdf and have the name of each worksheet named based on a specific cell (`C8`).

This is what I have so far (I'm still a beginner):

```
Sub print_pdf()

    Dim wb As String
    Dim ws As String
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim I As Integer    

    'For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
     ws = Activeworkbooks.Worksheets.Count

    For I = 1 To ws
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set rng = ws.Range("C8")

    ws.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=ws.Range("C8"),      Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=False, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

Next ws    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see a few issues with the code you posted. This should get you started, it does not include error checking (that there is a valid value in C8, the file does not already exist, etc.)

```
Sub print_pdf()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rngFileName As String
Dim I As Integer

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

For I = 1 To Worksheets.Count
    wb.Worksheets(I).Activate
    rngFileName = "C:\Temp\" & Range("C8").Value & ".pdf"
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        rngFileName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=False, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
        False
Next I
End Sub
```

I tested the code on Excel 2010 and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this which includes error handling to capture any problems with the sheet names

Note that:

1. `For each ws` is superior to looping by sheet count
2. No need to activate the sheet before saving it
3. This code saves to the same path as the `ActiveWorkbook`
4. Error handling is important for invalid file save names
5. If you have duplicate values in `C8` the earlier value(s) will be overwritten on export, the code can be adpated to test for this

*code*

```
Sub ToPDF()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim strMsg As String
If ActiveWorkbook.Path = vbNullString Then Exit Sub
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
On Error Resume Next
ws.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & ws.[C8]
If Err.Number <> 0 Then strMsg = strMsg & ws.Name & vbNewLine
On Error GoTo 0
Next
If Len(strMsg) > 0 Then MsgBox strMsg, vbCritical, "errors"
End Sub
```